# removing rows without returns incorrect result

Tags: r

I am trying to remove rows that do not have a number in them based on one column. I assumed this would be a straightforward process, but I am running into an issue:

```
> head(cond$Q26)
[1] "1"                                "1"                                ""                                
[4] "Q26"                              "Click to write the question text" "1"                               
> cond<-cond[is.numeric(cond$Q26)]
> head(cond)
data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows
```

Anyone have a suggestion on how I can fix this? Im stuck without having an error message.

Comment: It would have been necessary to use `as.numeric`, rather than `is.numeric`, and then test with `!is.na`. Try : `cond <- cond[!is.na(as.numeric(cond$Q26)), ]`  ... not forgetting the comma if you want this to select rows rather than columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep` to match zero or more non-numeric characters (`\\D*`) from the start (`^`) of the string to the end (`$`) and use that to subset the rows of 'cond'.

```
cond1 <- cond[grepl('^\\D*$', cond$Q26),, drop=FALSE]
cond1
#                             Q26
#3                                 
#5 Click to write the question text
```

If we need to get only rows with numeric elements on 'Q26', just negate the above

```
cond[!grepl('^\\D*$', cond$Q26),, drop=FALSE]
```

#### data

```
cond <- data.frame(Q26 = c(1, 1, '', 'Q26', 'Click to write the question text', 1),
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```